# Cassandra MAX function returning mismatched rows

Tags: cassandra

Hi I am trying to get the max coauthor publication from a table in Cassandra, however its returning me mismatched rows when I query
`select coauthor_name, MAX(num_of_colab) AS max_2020 from coauthor_by_author where pid = '40/2499' and year=2020;`.

It returns:
[image]

which is wrong because 9 belongs to another coauthor.

Here is my create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coauthor_by_author (
        pid text,
        year int,
        coauthor_name text,
        num_of_colab int,
        PRIMARY KEY ((pid), year, coauthor_name, num_of_colab)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year desc);
```

As proof, here is part of the original table:

[image]

[image]

As you can see Abdul Hanif Bin Zaini number publication as coauthor should only be 1.

Comment: You need to include more representative data.  Anybody would be guessing as to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `MAX()` function is working as advertised but I think your understanding of how it works is incorrect. Let me illustrate with an example.

Here is the schema for my table of authors:

```
CREATE TABLE authors_by_coauthor (
    author text,
    coauthor text,
    colabs int,
    PRIMARY KEY (author, coauthor)
)
```

Here is a sample data of authors, their corresponding co-authors, and the number of times they collaborated:

```
 author  | coauthor  | colabs
---------+-----------+--------
    edda | ramakanta |      5
    edda |    ruzica |      9
   anita |   dakarai |      8
   anita |    sophus |     12
   anita |      uche |      4
 cassius |    ceadda |     14
 cassius |  flaithri |     13
```

Anita has three co-authors:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM authors_by_coauthor WHERE author = 'anita';

 author | coauthor | colabs
--------+----------+--------
  anita |  dakarai |      8
  anita |   sophus |     12
  anita |     uche |      4
```

And the top number of collaborations for Anita is `12`:

```
SELECT MAX(colabs) FROM authors_by_coauthor WHERE author = 'anita';

 system.max(colabs)
--------------------
                 12
```

Similarly, Cassius has two co-authors:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM authors_by_coauthor WHERE author = 'cassius';

 author  | coauthor | colabs
---------+----------+--------
 cassius |   ceadda |     14
 cassius | flaithri |     13
```

with `14` as the most collaborations:

```
cqlsh> > SELECT MAX(colabs) FROM authors_by_coauthor WHERE author = 'cassius';

 system.max(colabs)
--------------------
                 14
```

Your question is incomplete since you haven't provided the full sample data but I suspect you're expecting to get the name of the co-author with the most collaborations. This CQL query will NOT return the result you're after:

```
SELECT coauthor_name, MAX(num_of_colab)
  FROM coauthor_by_author
  WHERE ...
```

In `SELECT coauthor_name, MAX(num_of_colab)`, you are incorrectly assuming that the result of `MAX(num_of_colab)` corresponds to the `coauthor_name`. Aggregate functions will only ever return ONE row so the result set only ever contains one co-author. The co-author `Abdul ...` just happens to be the first row in the result so is listed with the `MAX()` output.

When using aggregate functions, it only makes sense to specify the function in the `SELECT` statement on its own:

```
SELECT function(col_name) FROM table WHERE ...
```

Specifying other columns in the query selectors is meaningless with aggregate functions. Cheers!